# Action links on iOS devices not redirecting to the correct Action

Tags: actions-on-google

When using an action link on an iOS device, the user is asked to confirm that he wants to talk to the correct Action, but sometimes the answers yes / no are missing, and in any cases writing, saying or even selecting "yes" isn't understood properly.

You can see a screencast of the issue here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tOXvlur0Alruvz_idhgGlycQ1AOeeIxB/view?usp=sharing. The links used are:

Zurich Airport Action:

https://assistant.google.com/services/invoke/uid/00000069d5106943?intent=ai.airport.FLIGHT_SUBSCRIPTION&param.flightAggregatedId=ARRIVALLH118630-04-2020
https://assistant.google.com/services/invoke/uid/00000069d5106943?intent=ai.airport.FLIGHT_SUBSCRIPTION&param.flightAggregatedId=ARRIVALLX97101-05-2020

Milan Airports Action:

https://assistant.google.com/services/invoke/uid/000000e90a14a222?intent=ai.airport.FLIGHT_SUBSCRIPTION&param.flightAggregatedId=D_AZ_02071_2020-04-30
https://assistant.google.com/services/invoke/uid/000000e90a14a222?intent=ai.airport.FLIGHT_SUBSCRIPTION&param.flightAggregatedId=D_AZ_01027_2020-05-01

The above flow works as expected on an Android phone. Any idea what might be causing this?

---

Edit 2020-08-04

It has been confirmed by Google Assistant this was a bug on their side. It has since been fixed and is no longer an issue

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the 4 links today and it looks like they are all working as expected. meaning the action links of  Zurich Airport Action and Milan Airports Actions are both being triggered correctly.

I also watched your screencast. It looks like the behavior in your screencast is that it didn't trigger either of the airport Actions. The response you saw was actually from the Google Assistant.

You can reproduce the same behavior by opening Google Assistant app and say yes randomly, you will get the same responses, i.e cool, ok, etc

Comment: Hi @mandychannyc, thank you for your response. It was indeed a bug on Google Assistant's side where they didn't activate the correct action. It has been fixed a while ago, I will edit the question.